# Open file in adjacent directory

Tags: python-2.7, filepath

I have a python script that needs to open a file in another directory, the two directories share a common parent, but I dont know where the parent may be located and it needs to work across multiple OS.

```
-Parent
    -dir1
       -file.txt
    -dir2
       -script.py
```

I tried from another answer but it doesnt work:

```
import os.path
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.relpath('..\\Parent\\dir1\\file.txt', current_path)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as afile:
```

But I just get that the path isnt recognised (in this case on Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run multiple os we should use os.path.
Below Code can run script from any directory.

```
import os
script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
parent_path = os.path.dirname(script_path)
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep,parent_path,"dir1","file1.txt")

print file_path
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `os.chdir`:

```
os.chdir("../dir2")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution that works on Linux and Windows

```
import os.path
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path, "..", "dir1", "file.txt"))
with open(file_path, 'rb') as afile:
```